# Utf8 - How to clean these strings?

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

i use

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
```

Mysql database with "utf8_general_ci"

but i get these strings

- Saddle Club 3ã�​â&de​g;
- Speciale Aldo Moro02/04/�

How to clean all these strings?

Comment: How it looks like in database? (e.g. from phpMyAdmin)? What stands in database for "Saddle Club 3ã�​â&de​g;"?

Comment: Where do you get these strings from using what? THis needs more info.

Comment: "i get these strings" where, how?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the encoding of your mysql database connection.

```
$this->mysqli->query('SET NAMES utf8'); //on your mysqli instance
or
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8'); // simple mysql query
```

Don't know what type of connection do you use, but that might help..

Answer (score 0):

Do you use any utf-8 settings upon your queries?

Like:

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8", $this->connection);
mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8", $this->connection);
$result = mysql_query($sql, $this->connection);
```